# Opacity in nested div tag

Tags: html, css

I am looking for `css` a solution where I can set lower value of `opacity` for background color, and text over it will b completely opaque.

I tried this:

```
 <div style="opacity: 0.4; background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(242, 242, 242); ">
    <div style="opacity: 1;">
      Complete opaque text over background color
    </div>
 </div>
```

but this didn't work. Here opacity for both both background color and text are getting changed as per outer div opacity value.

Can anyone please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rgba` to set semi-transparent colors:

```
 <div style="background:rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.4);">
    <div>
      Complete opaque text over background color
    </div>
 </div>
```

The opacity of the child element will never be higher than the parent's opacity, if the parent's opacity is 0.4 then a child with opacity 1 will also be 0.4, a child with opacity 0.5 will be 0.2 etc.. It is calculated relatively to the parent's opacity.

For older IE versions use `filter` to achieve this effect or regular `rgb` as fallback for other old browsers